# Why does this factorial function return an int instead of a double

Tags: c++, function, integer, type-conversion, double

The type is a double up until it is returned, at which point it gets clipped to an integer. Why is this? Any help would be appreciated.

```
using namespace std;

double fac_counter = 1.0;


int factorial(double n) {

    for (double i = 1.0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        fac_counter = double(fac_counter)*i;
    }
    return fac_counter; 
}
```

Comment: Because that's what you wrote in the function signature.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting, even if you change the function type from `int` to `double`, the output is an `int` when using `cout` but when you use `printf()`, you get a double value, wondering why this is caused.

Answer (score 0):

Your return type is **int** change it to **double**

Answer (score 0):

```
int factorial(double n)
```

change it to

```
double factorial(double n)
```

The reason you were getting an int is because the return type of your function is int and what you wanted is a double.

I also noticed a strange behavior with you code. If I use

```
cout<<factorial(3);
```

I seem to get output `6`
But when I use

```
printf("%lf",factorial(3));
```

I get `6.000000`.

Comment: _"I also noticed a strange behavior with you code. If I use ..."_ have a look at [`std::setprecision()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) et al.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ, I tried `cout<<setprecision(6)<<factorial(3);`, but I am still getting the same result.